# Refer Topic and Subscription name from Configuration in an Azure Function with Service Bus Trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have an Azure Service Bus with Service Bus Topic trigger. My function looks something like this

```
[FunctionName("SbListener")]
        public static async Task Run(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("test-topic", "test-sub-1", Connection = "ServiceBus")]string message, 
            [Inject("Microsoft.EventStore.Functions", true)] IWebNotificationManagerFactory webNotificationManagerFactory,
            [Inject("Microsoft.EventStore.Functions", true)] ILogger logger)
        { ... }
```

The configuration for my Service Bus is in the local.settings.json file.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "ServiceBus": "Endpoint=sb://<my-sb>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=<my-key>"
}
```

What  I am looking for is that I want to refer the topic names from the configuration file as well, rather than hard-coding them in the `ServiceBusTrigger`. The problem is that in case I change the subscription name then I would have to re-deploy Function code (I want to avoid this at all cost).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Put topic and subscription in `Values` in local.settings.json(Application settings in portal) and reference them using app setting binding expressions--wrap the app setting name with `%`, check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#binding-expressions---app-settings).

```
[ServiceBusTrigger("%Topic%", "%Subscription%", Connection = "ServiceBus")]string message
```

Besides, I would suggest you put `ServiceBus` connection string in `Values` as well, `ConnectionStrings` is used by frameworks that typically get connection strings from the ConnectionStrings section of a configuration file, such as Entity Framework. See the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file).

Comment: Perfect! Not sure how I missed it.