# Reading TopicName from config for Azure Function Service Bus Trigger not working

Tags: azure, azure-functions, servicebus

I have a service bus trigger function where I want to load the topic name from config

I have seen this post and I have tried the same approach [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54828387/refer-topic-and-subscription-name-from-configuration-in-an-azure-function-with-s)

```
 public async Task MyFunctionAsync(
   [ServiceBusTrigger("%TopicName%", "data-subscription", Connection = "event-bus-connection")]
   string mySbMsg)
   {
   }
```

In my localsettings.json file I have

```
"bindings": [
    {
      "%TopicName%": "topic"
    }
  ]
```

"bindings": [
{
"%TopicName%": "rockit-notification-topic"
}
]

This doesnt work

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'MyFunction'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: '%TopicName%' does not resolve to a value.

Also, even if this did work, how do I add this to the settings of the function within the portal as this is an item in an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't add the "bindings" section to you localsettings file.
localsettings.json should look something like that:

```js
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "event-bus-connection": "test",
    "TopicName":"topic",
    "SubsriptionName":"data-subscription"
  }
}
```

On Azure Portal you can directly add it to App Service/Function Configuration like properies with name TopicName, SubsriptionName etc.

Comment: ok I will try this but without putting any %% marks how can it tell the difference between TopicName being a topic called TopicName, or a config setting?

Comment: @Paul your function declaration with %% is actually correct.
%TopicName% - means that value should be retrieved from config.
TopicName - means that the Topic name is 'TopicName'